# Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have this question from my statistical theory course:
A sniper shoots at a target. X and Y measure its deviation on the x and y axes. X and Y are independent and are distibuted normally with mean=0 and variance=$\sigma^2$. We are asked to calculate the PDF of R=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

This is the solution to this question:
[image]

I don't understand why the density that is placed in the integral is like that (in the red box). I'd love an explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A density of $(X,Y)$ can, by independence, be expressed as 
$$f(x,y)=\frac 1{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right),$$
and writing $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, we get the wanted expression (remember $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ for all $\theta$).

Comment: I understand the switch to polar coordinates. What I don't understand is how from the normal distribution of X and Y separately you got to the f(x,y).

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with respective densities $f$ and $g$, then a density of $(X,Y)$ is given by $H(x,y):=f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: Great! Thanks :D

Comment: You are welcome!